# How do I show rich snippets for workshop events in the Google search results?

Tags: seo, google, rich-snippets

I have a Workshops date in the Website, I want to show those workshop dates in Google search as shown in attached picture. How can i achieve this?

[image: How can I show date in the Google search as shown in the picture]

Comment: You need to learn about schema and rich text.  Here is something I found https://econsultancy.com/what-are-rich-search-results-and-how-can-you-get-them/ (and have no affiliation)

Comment: Google uses the term "rich snippets" for this type of display in the search results.  I edited your question to use that phrase.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This information (econsultancy.com/) really helps me to understand.